# Config variables not being resolved in middleware.json in Loopback 3

Tags: loopbackjs

I'm unable to get the `restApiRoot` variable to resolve when using it in middleware.json. I'm using Loopback 3. Here's my setup:

**config.json**

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api"
}
```

**middleware.json**

```
  "auth": {
    "./middleware/order-auth": {
      "paths": [
        "${restApiRoot}/Orders"
      ]
    }
  },
```

If I replace `${restApiRoot}` with `/api` then it works. I found [this issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/2455) which sounds identical, but their resolution was to update loopback and loopback-boot back in 2016, and my versions are well beyond this. My middleware.json matches my version (3) docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that loopback-boot performs variable substitution only when `}` is the last character. See the source code in [lib/plugin-base.js](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-boot/blob/2675771ec1237c33a7d782e994acf5bd08a85016/lib/plugin-base.js#L268-L296) (loopback-boot version 3.x):

```
var DYNAMIC_CONFIG_PARAM = /\$\{(\w+)\}$/;
function getConfigVariable(app, param, useEnvVars) {
  var configVariable = param;
  var match = configVariable.match(DYNAMIC_CONFIG_PARAM);
  // etc.
```

Comment: Right you are. Thanks Miroslav.